# Is there any way to validate device token?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am using push notification in my app and i want to send device token to my server only if deviceToken expired or device not resister on APNS.I can check device is resister or not by **iSResisterForRemoteNotification** But how can i check my current DeviceToken is Valid or Not.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888440/how-to-validate-apple-apn-device-token-wcf-net

Comment: There is no expiry for device token. Even if you uninstall the app and install again, the device token will be same for that app in that device. So no need to check for device token expiry. If you restore the OS and install the app again, the device token will change.

Comment: @Basheer Ok,If i resirster again and agian then token will not change right?

Comment: No. it will not change.